# Selecionar pasta/diretorio numa input

Tags: javascript, html

Ando a tentar criar algo que seja parecido com uma `input type="file"`, só que ao invés de carrega um ficheiro, teria de escolher uma pasta. Algo como a janela de "Guardar como", onde escolhemos a pasta para guardar o ficheiro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste exemplo, ia buscar a pasta `C:/Users/cesarcacao/Desktop`

Gostava de colocar alguma tentativa de código, mas não consegui ainda construir nada concreto.

Comment: Mas queres selecionar a path desse diretório?

Comment: Sim, a partida passa um pouco por ai. Por exemplo, na imagem que coloquei, ia buscar a pasta `C:/Users/cesarcacao/Desktop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe um atributo chamado **webkitdirectory**, na página do G+ do [Addy Osmani](https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/Dk5UhZ6zfF3) ele explica melhor como funciona, [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/addyo/Ha979/) uma demo.

```
<input type="file" multiple webkitdirectory id="pasta"/>
```

Testei aqui e funcionou no Chrome/Opera.

Por **razões de segurança** os navegadores atuais não permitem você obter o caminho completo do arquivo. Apenas o IE7 pra baixo, [fonte](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection)

Comment: Falta é selecionar só a *path* do diretório...

Comment: Pois, é isso que estou a tentar fazer, e é por isso que ainda não marquei a resposta como correta... Na verdade não estou a conseguir dar um alert da pasta

Comment: @CesarMiguel Por razões de segurança os navegadores atuais não permitem isso. Apenas o IE7 pra baixo permite isso. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx

Comment: @Laerte, adiciona essa informação na tua resposta, para responder a minha perguntar e poder marcar sff

Comment: Feito, @CesarMiguel.